# Is the word “shading” more related to “shadow” or “shade”?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I am interested in this more from a computer science perspective, but I figured this would be a better place to ask.

A sentence example would be,

> After applying shading the scene looks much more realistic.

Basically, how did the verb *shading* form?
What was the original noun for it?
And what does it mean outside computer science in English?

Comment: Typo in the title?

Comment: Your question is totally incomprehensible.

Comment: Do you realise that you've written the word, "shadow" three times in the title, but then you talk about "shading"? Is this some kind of riddle?

Comment: @sumelic  The question was basically how did the verb shading form ? What was the original noun for it ? And what does it mean outside computer science in English ?

Comment: Think about a lighter shade of gray.  *Shading* is related to that kind of shade.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The root verb is "shade".

Comment: "Shading" is the present participle of the verb "shade". "Shade" and "shadow" derive from the same Germanic roots, though the specific derivations are a bit convoluted.

Comment: @HotLicks and don't you think before voting to close as being unclear you could wait an hour or two and give the OP a chance to mend things? Or better explain in a comment why the question was incomprehensible?

Answer (score 1):

At first blush, I thought this was a frivolous question--but the etymology may seem interesting.

**Shadow** (verb), as used in the sense of darkening in an illustration, dates to the [**early 15th century**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shadow):

while [**Shade**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shade) (verb):

> c. 1400, "to screen from light or heat," from shade (n.). From 1520s as "to cast a shadow over;" figurative use in this sense from 1580s. ***Sense in painting and drawing is from 1797. In reference to colors, 1819***. Related: Shaded; shading.

source: etyonline

**So it would seem shading is more closely and recently linked to Shade.**

Comment: Why is is surprising?  "Shading", in the image-altering sense, is the application of *shades* of a color to the image.

Comment: @HotLicks I did not say it was surprising. And shading also refers "the darkening or coloring of an illustration or diagram with parallel lines....", I just thought they derived from the same word. They dont, not exactly.

Comment: "Shading" is the present participle of the verb "shade".  "Shade" and "shadow" derive from the same Germanic roots, though the specific derivations are a bit convoluted.  There's really nothing to see here ... move along.

Comment: @HotLicks I already had done...until I had to start answering comments;-)